# Best way of building an application having a UI like OUTLOOK?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, user-interface, outlook, ria

We are trying to build an application which has a UI like OUTLOOK?
Something which has a left navigation pane and then right side there is a details pane.

It would be a heavy on data side. We need to access Database numerous times to access the data to be displayed.

Is SILVERLIGHT a good option which will provide RIA effect? Or Should I stick to ASP.NET building aspx pages and giving it a rich effect with Ajax?

What are different ways of handling this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always thought ExtJS has a very Office 2007 Look and feel

http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/feed-viewer/view.html

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you look at WPF, it will be perfect for this type of application. It does have the advantages of both ASP.NET since you can create browser pages and also the UI capability of Silverlight, some people say WPF is like Silverlight with steroids.

Comment: That's ironic, because some people would say that silverlight is like a cut down version of WPF.

Comment: exactly my point, Silverlight is much like a cut down version of WPF, that is why I said WPF is like Silverlight with steroids... much stronger than regular Silverlight ;)

Comment: Ricardo, I dont want a desktop application. I am looking for a web application, so WPF is out of the way

Comment: There is such a thing as a WPF Browser application. Yes it's pretty far removed from web development, but you don't really make it clear that you are developing a web application when you open with "We are trying to build an application".

Comment: @SVI Got it, you did not specify that you wanted a web application, your example referred to a desktop application (Outlook).

Answer (score 0):

The RadControls from telerik have a built in Office and Outlook skin and provide all the different controls you want (grid, left panel bar, right grid, right scheduler)  Their controls are available for Silverlight, ASP.Net and WPF so you can try them both out and see what works for ya.

[Outlook grid example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/webmail/defaultcs.aspx)

[Outlook Panel Bar Navigation example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/applicationscenarios/outlooknavigation/defaultcs.aspx)

[Silverlight Scheduler](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Scheduler/FirstLook)

I'm using them and they're great.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use Silverlight or WPF then check out these blog posts on using the Prism framework to build a modular UI which looks like Outlook.

http://blogs.msdn.com/erwinvandervalk/archive/2009/03/02/how-to-build-an-outlook-style-application.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/erwinvandervalk/archive/2009/04/29/how-to-build-an-outlook-style-application-with-prism-v2-part-2.aspx

Prism (http://www.codeplex.com/prism) was designed to build just this sort of modular UI.

Ade

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to decide whether your users are OK with installing your application (WinForms, WPF etc) or if it has be run from a web browser (Silverlight, ExtJS, Ajax). Constructing an Outlook clone in a web environment is often more difficult (browser compatibility), and you can have issues with performance. However web applications are easier to update and maintain.

Consider usability too. For a desktop application Outlook may be a reasonable model to follow, but users often expect the web to work differently from desktop applications.

Comment: Brian, I want a web application. Winforms is not an option.